# error: consider creating fewer actors or increase the resources available to this Ray cluster

Tags: flow-project

I had this problem when I try to run on virtual box: python examples/train.py singleagent_traffic_light_grid.
I appreciate your time to help to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only have 1 CPU available on that machine. Try using the stable baseline examples instead, they can run if only 1 CPU is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had 2 Cpu on this machine, after I increasing the number of Cpus to 3, the command works.